# reference class instance in sinon.stub(myClass.prototype,'method').returns();

Tags: javascript, sinon, stub

How can I reference a class instance in a stub?

For example if I have the following class:

```
class myClass {
    x=11;
    myMethod(){return this.x.toString()}
}
```

I wanted to stub myMethod in all future instances of myClass but have the method still return the current instance of the class. I cannot simply do the following:

```
sinon.stub(myClass.prototype,'myMethod').returns(this.x.toString());
```

because `this` does not refer to current instance of the class.

Edit: Updated example so that myMethod processes `this` to return something else rather than just returning `this` directly

Answer (score 0):

It should be `stub.returnsThis();`. E.g.

`index.ts`:

```js
export class MyClass {
  myMethod() {
    return this;
  }
}
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import { MyClass } from './';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import { expect } from 'chai';

describe('60838564', () => {
  it('should return instance', () => {
    sinon.stub(MyClass.prototype, 'myMethod').returnsThis();
    const myClass = new MyClass();
    const actual = myClass.myMethod();
    expect(actual).to.be.instanceOf(MyClass);
    expect(actual).to.be.equal(myClass);
  });
});
```

unit test results:

```sh
  60838564
    ✓ should return instance


  1 passing (12ms)
```

Comment: Thanks For your answer. Unfortunately I oversimplified my example. Please see edit.